# Why do I get 2 hits with different data from PayPal's IPN?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

After I make a simple web transaction on my site, my IPN handler recieves not just the one expected 'completed' hit, but 2 hits. Each with different data. The first looks like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
[transaction] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [invoiceId] => PVIFmMOZTm2xkjbs
                [id_for_sender_txn] => 3M760109N8943254L
                [receiver] => me@gmail.com
                [is_primary_receiver] => false
                [id] => 08B29244UF9480324
                [status] => Completed
                [paymentType] => GOODS
                [status_for_sender_txn] => Completed
                [pending_reason] => NONE
                [amount] => GBP 50.00
            )

    )

[payment_request_date] => Wed Sep 18 12:55:36 PDT 2013
[return_url] => http://mysite.com/checkout/paypal-overlay-state/complete
[fees_payer] => EACHRECEIVER
[ipn_notification_url] => http://mysite.com/ipn
[sender_email] => buyer@gmail.co.uk
[verify_sign] => AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31ASUp2KT0F-R3d2QqGIzfWpkS.gWz
[test_ipn] => 1
[cancel_url] => http://mysite.com/checkout/paypal-overlay-state/cancel
[pay_key] => AP-4V279017Y7501703X
[action_type] => PAY
[memo] => SOMETHING
[transaction_type] => Adaptive Payment PAY
[tracking_id] => PVIFmMOZTm2xkjbs
[status] => COMPLETED
[log_default_shipping_address_in_transaction] => false
[charset] => windows-1252
[notify_version] => UNVERSIONED
[reverse_all_parallel_payments_on_error] => false
)
```

the second looks like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
[mc_gross] => 50.00
[invoice] => PVIFmMOZTm2xkjbs
[protection_eligibility] => Ineligible
[payer_id] => NRQL7RKB54XWY
[tax] => 0.00
[payment_date] => 12:57:41 Sep 18, 2013 PDT
[payment_status] => Completed
[charset] => windows-1252
[first_name] => Ashley
[mc_fee] => 1.90
[notify_version] => 3.7
[custom] => 
[payer_status] => unverified
[business] => me@gmail.com
[quantity] => 0
[verify_sign] => AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AJGmBkDrCSx-mp-dKf5.Wc6co3ra
[payer_email] => payer@gmail.co.uk
[memo] => SOMETHING
[txn_id] => 08B29244UF9480324
[payment_type] => instant
[last_name] => Ward
[receiver_email] => me@gmail.com
[payment_fee] => 
[receiver_id] => XSSCKHZJZRBDQ
[txn_type] => web_accept
[item_name] => 
[mc_currency] => GBP
[item_number] => 
[residence_country] => GB
[test_ipn] => 1
[receipt_id] => 2722-5250-1650-6726
[transaction_subject] => 
[payment_gross] => 
[ipn_track_id] => a503d9ea64b1e
)
```

How do I make sense of this data? Why are there 2 hits? and which is the one I need to look out for?

The array shown is a direct print out of the PHP $_POST array for each request. You can see from the timestamps that the one IPN arrives slightly before the second.

**EDIT:**

I have come to the understanding that the first array (first IPN hit), is an additional reciept you get when you are using the Adaptive Payments API.

For most use cases, I believe this can be ignored, as the second IPN hit contains all the useful data you will need.

Although one caveat is that the second, more useful,IPN array comes 2 mins after the first. The first IPN hit arrives immediately after the payment is processed, while the second does not come until 2 mins after this... not sure why this is...

Thanks!

Comment: Your "second" IPN has timestamp of 2 mins earlier than the "first" one ;) What's your product?

Comment: Yes I'm not sure why this is, it's a normal "Goods" payment using the Adaptive Payments API and the PayPal JS Overlay

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your initial definition of an hit I believe. Or you may defined a variable incorrectly which is why you are getting 2 hits

Comment: I'm getting 2 seperate post requests. The array shown is a direct print out of the PHP $_POST array for each request. You can see from the timestamp that one request earlier than the next